# Is it possible in OpenAL to directly choose a recording device?

Tags: java, openal

I have never worked with OpenAL before, and have been looking at some example code.  However, before I start testing code in my program, I want to know if there's a way to select a specific recording device for input (perhaps by way of a combo box with different microphones).  I know it isn't possible in the Java Sound API, which is why I'm inquiring about AL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Get the list of devices. Prompt the user to select one. Set it with `alcCaptureOpenDevice`.

See [ALC11 API](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/openal/ALC11.html).

Something like:

```
String[] capDevices = ALC11.alcGetString(null, ALC11.ALC_CAPTURE_DEVICE_SPECIFIER).split("\0");
for (int i = 0; i < capDevices.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Capture device "+ i + ": " + capDevices[i]);
}
//Selection code goes here
String chosenDevice = ...;

ALCdevice device = ALC11.alcCaptureOpenDevice(chosenDevice, freq, format, bufferSize);
```

(Disclaimer: Haven't compiled/tested)